# How is working multiple loss layer using caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

Make some networks like that

```
Conv(1-1)-Conv(1-2)-Loss1-Conv(2-1)-Conv(2-2)-Loss2
```

When I train this networks using caffe, How is working?
Conv(2-1) and Conv(2-2) are updated using Loss2. I can get it.

But how is updating weights in the Conv(1-1) and Conv(1-2)?
Only using Loss1? or Using summations both gradient from Conv(2-1) and gradient from Loss1?

Answer (score 0):

Caffe (like other SGD based solvers) uses the chain rule to compute derivatives. The loss of your net is the sum of both loss layers and the gradients estimated are the gradients of the overall loss. The derivative of loss1 w.r.t conv2's parameters is zero, thus loss1 has no effect on the update of conv2's params, as expected.

Comment: Yes, loss1 has no effect to conv2's weights. How about conv1's weight?? You mean just all of conv layers updated by overall loss(sum of both loss layers)?

Comment: @HotaekHan computing the gradients of the net is quite simple thanks to the chain rule: it allows to "break" the computation to a layer-by-layer product. If you look at a loss which is a sum of two terms, then the gradient is a sum of two derivatives, accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your kind.